# POST request through Guzzle php

Tags: php, json, post, request, guzzle

hi i wanted to make a post request to dropbox.i found there is this guzzle which can be easily send http req using php. here the http code given by dropbox

```
    `POST /2/files/list_folder
    Host: https://api.dropboxapi.com
    User-Agent: api-explorer-client
    Authorization: Bearer <access-token>
    Content-Type: application/json
    {
    "path": "",
    "recursive": false,
    "include_media_info": true,
    "include_deleted": false,
    "include_has_explicit_shared_members": false
    }`
```

This is my php code i coded for above request;

```
$response=$client->request('POST','https://api.dropboxapi.com',
[
    'headers'=>[
        'Authorization'=>'Bearer '.$API,
        'User-Agen'=>'api-explorer-client',
        'Content-Type'=>'application/json'
    ],
    'form_params'=>[

            'path'=>'',
            'recursive'=>'false',
            'include_media_info'=> 'true',
            'include_deleted'=> 'false',
            'include_has_explicit_shared_members'=> 'false'

    ]
]);

$headers = $response->getHeaders();
$body =$response->getBody();
$print=json_decode($body,true);
//Output headers and body for debugging purposes
var_dump($headers);echo"<br><br>";
var_dump($print);?>
```

this should give something similar to following ,but i get a small array

```
    {"entries": [
{
".tag": "folder",
  "name": "Photos",
  "path_lower": "/photos",
  "path_display": "/Photos",
  "id": "id:bwGPfg_v6ZUAAAAAAAAAOA"
},`
```

what i missed here? 
PS:im new to php related stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending JSON, not an HTML form. So use `'json'` instead of `'form_params'`.